# why does an object created from a JSON file include a "default" key?

Tags: javascript, json

While running some data validation methods against a JS object that was created by importing a JSON file the `checkDataForExtraKeys` validation has flagged a key called "default" as being unexpected.  When a `console.log` is done against this object, sure enough, there is a key in it called "default" which contains all of the JSON content.  Here is a simple [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/object-from-a-json-object-had-a-key-called-default-q5d2t?file=/src/index.js) to demonstrate.

Why does the object made from JSON data have this "default" key?  An object created directly in a JS file does not get such a key added automatically.

Is there a way to prevent the object created from the JSON data from having the "default" key added?

Comment: Not too familiar with ES6 import but just `import imported from "./config.json"` seems to import it correctly (same syntax as importing the default export). I'd guess that since ES6 modules usually have named exports or a default export, when you import a JSON file (with no explicit exports) it provides the default export this way.

Comment: Yes!  That fixed it.

Comment: @JonathanLam you should add as an answer.